# How do I find if any of the characters in my list are present in a field?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, character

I have a dataset df_ae.
I have created a list of modalities:

```
main_modals <- c("X ray Units Static", "X ray Units Mobile", "CT", "Mammography", "MRI", "Nuclear Medicine", "Ultrasound")
```

I want to create a new column which will give "priority" if one of the main modals is present in the "modality" column and "non-priority" if none of the main modals are present.

I tried the following code:

```
df_ae$main_modal <- df_ae %>% ifelse(Modality == main_modals, "PRIORITY", "NON-PRIORITY")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in ifelse(., Modality == main_modals, "PRIORITY", "NON-PRIORITY") : 
  unused argument ("NON-PRIORITY")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mutate function from the dplyr package and case_when. This is not the task of ifelse function.

```
library(dplyr)

main_modals <- c("X ray Units Static", "X ray Units Mobile", "CT", "Mammography", "MRI", "Nuclear Medicine", "Ultrasound")

df_ae <- df_ae %>%
  mutate(main_modal = case_when(
    any(Modality %in% main_modals) ~ "PRIORITY",
    TRUE ~ "NON-PRIORITY"
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem as follows (I assume data `df_ae` is a *data.frame* object):

```
df_ae$main_modal <- ifelse(df_ae$Modality %in% main_modals, "PRIORITY", "NON-PRIORITY")

 # or
library(dplyr)

df_ae <- df_ae %>%
  mutate(main_modal = if_else(Modality %in% main_modals, "PRIORITY", "NON-PRIORITY"))

 # or
library(data.table)

setDT(df_ae)[, main_modal := fifelse(Modality %in% main_modals, "PRIORITY", "NON-PRIORITY")]
```